# Cursor moves last line when space tapped in the middle of word in UITextview

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have some text in UITextview, but when i tap a space in between any words the cursor goes to the end of textview. Please help really weird at this situation.

Comment: have you set the delegates? and using them properly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement below textview delegate method, i think you have written some unwanted code in that.

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

Comment: then definitely its doing something tricky..because its not the default behaviour of UITextView that happening with you.

Comment: Yes thats what Im confused. Is there any way to control cursor?

Comment: please post your UITextView implementation code? so that i can suggest you.